# A letter or symbol above a tensor

Tags: tensor

I would like to put a letter, e.g. `\lambda`, above a tensor, e.g. Riemann tensor, by which I mean a tensor that is function of `\lambda`.
I use `\tensor` and `\overset` command to construct this object. Here the code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
\[ \overset{\lambda}{\tensor{R}{^a_b_c_d}} \]
\end{document}
```

But that's not what I searching for, because the `\lambda` stand over entire tensor and not over the letter of tensor (here R).
Can somebody help me?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please provide a fully compilable minimal example. FOr example I do not know where `\tensor` comes from.

Comment: Have you tried `\tensor{\overset{\lambda}{R}}{^a_b_c_d}` ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom I guess that is no good alternative, as then the superscript `a` will be typeset above `\lambda`, at least with `\tensor` from package `tensor`

Comment: @cauchy42 Exactly. I don't want this.

Comment: @daleif Sorry. I'll correct it. `\tensor` is a command from package `tensor`, that allow to write tensors with many indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following "dirty" trick with `\vphantom`

```
\overset{\lambda}{R}\tensor{\vphantom{R}}{^a_b_c_d}
```

This works with the package `\tensor`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
\[ \overset{\lambda}{R}\tensor{\vphantom{R}}{^a_b_c_d} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! A nice "dirty" trick! 
But faithfully I don't understand the code!
May you please explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @H.B. As a matter of taste: If you use `\tensor*` instead of `\tensor`, the subscripts will be starting after `R` and don't leave the space due to the superscript `a`.

Comment: @cauchy42 Interesting remark, but I think the option might be harmful, because `\tensor*{R}{^a_b_c_d}` and `\tensor*{R}{_b^a_c_d}` are actually different things !

Comment: Oh yes, that's right.

Comment: @H.B. `\vphantom` does not typeset anything, but it reserves vertical space for its argument (here the second `R`). So you have two objects here: One is the `R` with the overset `\lambda`, the other a tensor object with "nothing" (but vertical space) in it, followed by the indices. As the `\vphantom` has no width, there will be no space between the printed and the "virtual" `R`

Comment: @cauchy42 Thanks! If I understood correctly, the argument of `\vphantom` is not important here. I can type simply `\vphantom{}`.

Comment: @H.B. No, the argument defines, how much vertical space is reserved. So you get a different height for `\vphantom{a}` then for `\vphantom{b}` then for `\phantom{\int}`. Typing `\vphantom{}` really gets you nothing. And as you want it precisely as high as an `R` is, you need to put `R` as argument.

Comment: @cauchy42 Great! Got it! Thank you guys!